# Does oxygen introduced during bottling get consumed by the yeast during carbing / conditioning?

Tags: bottling, carbonation, oxygenation

I was just thinking about oxidization at bottling time...

If you (accidentally) introduced oxygen into your beer when bottling, wouldn't this be used by the yeast the same way it is when you oxygenate your wort before fermentation?

IE, wouldn't any oxygen in your beer merely be used by the suspended yeast to multiply before the yeast switches back over to anaerobic metabolic pathways and begin to consume the sugars?

Comment: I think you'll have a hard time not getting any oxygen in the bottle. With a bottling rod, you'll have the volume of the rod, for example. You might also risk exploding bottles without any head space. I usually have 1.5cm of air in the bottle neck, and the beer is always fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aerobic is for propagation, anaerobic converts sugar into alcohol and carbon dioxide. I doubt a small amount would hurt, like from transfer or minor splashing, but if you intentionally injected oxygen, like how you might aerate the wort prior to fermentation, I would imagine it would not carbonate well and produce a lot of yeast, giving it a "yeasty" character.